# Not able to access smartedit url https://localhost:9002/smartedit

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud

I followed the steps provided in the wiki to install smartedit.
After installation of the same.. I tried to access the smartedit url https://localhost:9002/smartedit. But it is throwing 404 page and the following exception:

```
error expected mime type application octet stream but got text

<html>
<head>
<meta http equiv="Content Type" content="text/html;charset=utf 8"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body>HTTP ERROR 404
<p>Problem accessing /solr/master_backoffice_backoffice_product_flip/update. Reason:Not Found
</body>
</html>
```

We were using 6.3 earlier where we did not use smartedit. Now we are upgrading to 1811 and are trying to have smartedit functionality. Any leads would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: were the smartedit extensions added to the localextension.xml file ?

Comment: yes @dj_frunza, followed all the steps provided in wiki, the steps with grunt confuses me though! Do we need to have grunt set up?

Answer (score 3):

To make sure, you have properly installed this extension, you have to head up to hAC->Platform->Extensions and check if you can see smartedit on the list (see the uploaded screnshot). If there's no sign of smartedit, you have failed to install it properly.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HC6M.png)